# Storing and Calling Index Path Swift

Tags: swift

I have a collection view in swift in where it needs to store which button is pressed last. These buttons consist of A, B, C, D, this is like a quiz game.

[image]

Code:

```
extension QuestionCell {
func configure(with model: QuestionCellModel) {
    factLabel.text = model.fact
    questionLabel.text = model.question

    let views = answersStack.arrangedSubviews
    for view in views {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    for (index, answer) in model.answers.enumerated() {
        print(index)
        let answerLabel = UILabel()
        answerLabel.text = answer

        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerLabel)

        let answerButton = UIButton()
        answerButton.tag = index
        let imageNormal = UIImage(named: "circle_empty")
        answerButton.setImage(imageNormal, for: .normal)
        let imageSelected = UIImage(named: "circle_filled")
        answerButton.setImage(imageSelected, for: .selected)
        answerButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        answerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        answersStack.addArrangedSubview(answerButton)

    }
}
```

So with this it is able to print the index, but it should know which was the last button they selected, when they were done (Buttons: A,B,C,D). Based on the index it should store assigned values of each collection view cell(There are 5 question in the quiz). I have not figured out a way on how to solve this question because I am not sure the computer will store multiple index's in the collection view(Like how would the computer know when you click the done with quiz button what was the last index it chose for each question?) I hope this makes sense!

Thanks